# Regular expression to split geo-coordinates from a String

Tags: java, android, regex

I have geo-coordinates in a String like the one given below.

```
[79.9016492,6.8632761]
```

I need to get the two numbers separated as double values. Can someone please help me with writing a regular expression?

Comment: Sure,we will help you. First show what you have tried. Hints to start : **String**, **replace**,**Split**

Comment: is it String or String[] ?

Comment: @Jhanvi It's String. OP mentioned that `a String like the one given below.`

Comment: No need for regex.  Too expensive for such a simple job.  As Suresh says, string.split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `[79.9016492,6.8632761]` string, it is

```
String[] oxoy = "[79.9016492,6.8632761]".split("[\\[\\],]"); 
String x = oxoy[1]; // 79.9016492
String y = oxoy[2]; // 6.8632761
```

[**Ideone DEMO**](http://ideone.com/JHCmnw)

Convert to double

```
Double x1 = Double.valueOf(x);
Double y1 = Double.valueOf(y);
```

Comment: Elegant and oneliner. Good job, +1 well earned.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly regex, but you can get it very easily as follows:

```
String[] a = "[79.9016492,6.8632761]".split(",");
double x = Double.valueOf(a[0].substring(1));
double y = Double.valueOf(a[1].substring(0,a[1].length()-1));
```